# Can't override 404 page in Wordpress because of cPanel or server

Tags: wordpress, custom-error-pages

I have 404.php file in my theme folder, .htaccess looks like that

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Permalinks are set to post name, but the most important thing is that every page on my server have the same problem independently of theme. What can be a problem? In cPanel "Error Pages" I don't have anything set.

I have simply 404 page which is certainly not from WordPress. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Drwp.jpg)

Comment: Does your server have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Hmm not sure how I am able to check it via cPanel

Comment: Best contact your hosting support to check if unsure.

Comment: Ok, I have had enabled it already.

Comment: Check if cpanel apache2/nginx config have some options about customising error pages. As you can specify specific template file from server config per HTTP error code.

Comment: @Mtxz I only know I have nginx on my server, but nothing more. in /usr/ there is only /sbin/ nothing else, in /etc/ also don't have any related directories

Comment: Do you have access to some nginx settings from your cpanel?